# Asp.net mvc role based authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, rbac, role-base-authorization

I created a new web application and chose organizational as authentication type. I have the app tied to my office 365 account. In azure I was able to create roles and able to assign to users. My question is how do I allow my web application to take advantage of these roles either using controller annotation (eg `Authorize(Role=admin)`) or using the method `User.IsInRole()`?

Answer (score 1):

I use controller annotation, but for individual accounts with roles. I guess it's the same for organizational accounts. The benefit from using authorize attribute is that the attribute can be added for whole controller, unlike `User.IsInRole()` in every action.

[Authorize attribute example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.roles%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)